# Rails: translation missing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I am trying to learn ruby on rails. And when doing internationalisation, I'm getting the error:

> translation missing: en.store.index.title_html

Below is my `en.yml` file

```
en:
  layouts:
    application: 
      title: "Pragmatic book shelf"
      home: "Home"
      questions: "Questions"
      news: "News"
      contact: "Contact"

  store:
    index:
    title_html: "Your Pragmatic Catalog" 
    add_html: "Add to Cart"
```

I have searched the solution, and it says allow only spaces in en.yml file. It's already written with only spaces. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You must add the proper indentation under the index key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must add the proper indentation under the index key.

```
en:
  store:
    index:
      title_html: "Your Pragmatic Catalog" 
      add_html: "Add to Cart"
```

For accessing `title_html` with your current code, it'll be right after store, as you do with `index` (the three keys under the same `store` key):

```
en.store.title_html
```

Comment: Thanks. It fixed my issue.

Comment: How are you accessing those translations?, can you add that to the question?

Comment: Sorry.. It was my bad... in both files, I kept en: instead of es: in es.yml. Fixed. Working fine. Thank you.. :)